# How can I show a specified value at inputText?(XPages)

Tags: javascript, xpages, field, return-value

I have a form like the following figure.

If the first item Days has a value, it will show out "Division processing".

How can I write the code in "Purchase progress"?

Maybe like this?

```
var doc = purchase.getDocument();
var DAY_A0 = doc.getItemValue("DAY_A0"); //DAY_A0 = 1
if(DAY_A0 == "")
   return false;
else
   return "Division processing";
```

[image]

On the contrary, if the first item Days is a null value, the "Division processing" will not show out.

Like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_10.0.0/reference/r_domino_Document_getItemValue.html) getItemValue returns an java.util.Vector.

> **getItemValue(name:string) : java.util.Vector**
>
> *Return value*
> java.util.Vector
>
> *Description*
> The value or values contained in the item. The data type of the value depends on the data type of the item.

To check if there is something in the vector you need to generate an iterator and cycle through (example from linked help):

```
if (doc.hasItem(itemname)) {
    var itemvalues:java.util.Vector = doc.getItemValue(itemname);
    var iterator = itemvalues.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        var itemvalue = iterator.next();
        //do your check here...
    }
}
```

But there is a much easier way: Use `getItemValueString`. Then your above code works exactly as you want it to:

```
var DAY_A0 = doc.getItemValueString("DAY_A0"); //DAY_A0 = 1
```